# Printing a regular expression over multiple lines

Tags: regex, unix, sed, lines

I'm trying to search and print (ONLY) sections that contain some identifier, in a given file. The sections are delimited by starting and ending tags, and stretch over multiple lines. The task need to be done by unix commands.

For example, for the following lines:

```
start:
    blah..blah
    666
    blah blah..
end:
start:
    blah..blah
    1234
    blah blah..
end:
start:
    blah..blah
    8020
    blah blah..
end:
```

i would like to print the section that strats with 'start' and ends with 'end', say for the identifier 1234:

```
start:
    blah..blah
    1234
    blah blah..
end:
```

Your assistance is welcome.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18743576/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/start:/{:a;N;/end:/!ba;/1234/p}' file
```

Gather up lines between `start:` and `end:` and print them if the collection also contains `1234`.

Answer (score 0):

Flip-flop in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -ne '
    if ( $range = ( m/\Astart:/ .. m/\Aend:/ ) ) { 
        $s .= $_; 
        if ( $range =~ /E0\Z/ ) {
            if ( $s =~ m/(?m)^\s*1234\s*$/ ) {
                print $s;
            }
            undef $s;
        }
    }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
start:
    blah..blah
    1234
    blah blah..
end:
```